# Coming up with loop invariants involving k?

Tags: algorithms

```
void min(arr[], n){
for(i = 0;i < n; ++i)
{
   // Change < to > if you want to find the smallest element
   if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
       arr[i] = arr[i+1];
}
```

To avoid wording about a "just check my work" question. I will try to explain what I do not understand about this topic of loop invaraints. I have been having the hardest time coming up with the beginning loop variant with respect to the variables and the what they mean in relation to the arrays. So, my question about this code loop invariant is that this program finds the smallest element in the array. My loop invaraiant is At the start of the iteration when i = k, the item at index k is the smallest item in the range from zero to k. Can you tell me both if I have the correct loop invariant and also am I understanding the concept correctly. I believe that I need to relate such variables such as i, and j in loops with the varaible k in relation to what the program is doing. Thank you.

Comment: You mention $k$, but I don't see a $k$ in the program.

Comment: There is an implicit misconception in your question. You say "Can you tell me both if I have **the** correct loop invariant". There is no one loop invariant, but a whole collection of propositions which validity is preserved by the loop. Some might be stronger than others, some might be incomparable. So, there doesn't need to be one that is the correct one either.

Comment: You can test your proposition with examples like $[1,2,0,2]$. The first iteration doesn't make any change, the second turns it into $[1,0,0,2]$ and the third doesn't make any change. If what you meant is that `arr[i]` is the minimum of the prefix `arr[:i]`, you can see that this property is not satisfied, for example, after the first and after the third iteration.

Comment: Consider the following proposition: $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}: 0\leq k\leq i-1, \operatorname{arr}[k-1]\leq \operatorname{arr}[k] \vee \operatorname{arr}[k]\leq \operatorname{arr}[k+1]$, where we interpret $\operatorname{arr}[-1]$ to be $\leq$ when compared to any possible value that $\operatorname{arr}[0]$ can contain.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to determine whether you have the correct loop invariant:

1. Can you prove that it holds when entering the loop?
2. Can you prove that the loop maintains it?
3. Can you deduce correctness of the algorithm using the invariant?

I trust that you can do all these checks yourself.